# Missing android version in gradle android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

so I forked a project on github and I'm now trying to get the project to run in Android Studio. I downloaded all the SDK etc but I can't set the android version anywhere. I have one build.gradle file that looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How do I get the build.gradle file for modules to put my android dependencies in?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Make sure that you have build.gradle file in both app folder as well as project folder.

Comment: There are 2 build.gradle. Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle/2161/configure-your-build-with-gradle/7075/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project#t=201612291117522131357

Answer (score 0):

There should be at least two build.gradle files, one is in Project folder `MyProject\build.gradle` and the other one is in android app folder `MyProject\app\build.gradle` you should look in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There should be two build.gradle files. Which file you have post here it's a top-level build file.

The top-level build.gradle file, located in the root project directory, defines build configurations that apply to all modules in your project. and this file doesn't have android versions normally.

Another Build File should be there which is called Module-level Build File.

The module-level build.gradle file, located in each project/module/ directory, allows you to configure build settings for the specific module it is located in. It has android versions in android tag.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm seeing that the .gitignore contains the gradle file I'm looking for. Is there another possibility to generate that module gradle file?

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps, working fine for me:-

```
Select Project from top --> gradle --> wrapper --> gradle-wrapper-properties--> change in distributionUrl--> gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

After that change classpath in project level gradle i.e build.gradle(Project)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Comment: try 2.10 in gradle-wrapper-properties and classpath as 2.1.0

Comment: This is the right solution..I have tried it once again and its working fine..Let me know your error after trying this.